# LocationAssist Android Issue Fake GPS on android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location

Can u help me I have Problem when I using Detect fake gps, OS < 10 it's work but on API >29 not working fine..

I used [this](https://github.com/klaasnotfound/LocationAssistant#locationassistant)

working but on API<29 was call on

`onNeedLocationSettingsChange()`

not call this method
`onMockLocationsDetected()`
I'm try for manual check but not working too, I was tired..
I'm junior on android, everyone can help give me examples to fix this ?
thank you have a good day .

Comment: Stop using libraries from 4 years ago, especially the ones that involves location since android changes something almost on every os release

Comment: helo thanks for answer, do you have examples code for detect ismocklocation working fine at os 10 and higer or lower :( I was confused for fix this